# Elasticsearch NEST SDK throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, aws-elasticsearch

I am getting this exception from Elasticsearch .net client - NEST v7.10.0.

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
 ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.SetSpecialTypes[TResponse](String mimeType, Byte[] bytes, IMemoryStreamFactory memoryStreamFactory, TResponse& cs)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.SetBodyAsync[TResponse](ApiCallDetails details, RequestData requestData, Stream responseStream, String mimeType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.ResponseBuilder.ToResponseAsync[TResponse](RequestData requestData, Exception ex, Nullable`1 statusCode, IEnumerable`1 warnings, Stream responseStream, String mimeType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.RequestAsync[TResponse](RequestData requestData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearchAsync[TResponse](RequestData requestData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.RequestAsync[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)
```

What should be done to resolve this issue?
I am trying to query AWS elasticsearch cluster to get the results which seems to be very large in size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your client version to the latest version and also check Elasticsearch Nest official issue thread:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4697